# PyQT - list QWidgets/Windows

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qwidget, qmainwindow

I have a

```
class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
```

That is able to click>spawn a x number of windows that are:

```
class dataWindow(QtGui.QWidget)
```

Is there a way in PyQt to now find all spawned dataWindow's and get their objectName? 
each window has unique objectName. 
I tried going via :

```
a= self.findChild(QWidget, self.newDataWids[0]["window_name"]) - as I have all names stored in dict upon creation
```

but it only returns None. I think its because the dataWindow are not parented to Main window class I believe... so I either have to parent them - not sure how. Or somehow find them out in the "wild"...

Any ideas would be great.
Regards, Dariusz

Edit_1: A glitch in my code bugged out my current attempt. After relooking I managed to get it to work. I simply stored the window in temporary dictionary and then used that to retrieve access to window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You parent objects by passing in the parent to their constructor.  You'll have to check the documentation for each widget to get the correct argument position.

```
widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Button Text', self)
```

But really, you shouldn't have to do a search for children to get the child windows.  Your main window should be keeping handles to them.

```
def __init__(...)
    ...
    self._windows = []

def createSubWindow(self):
    window = WindowClass(self)
    self._windows.append(window)
```

Comment: Hey case sorted, but sadly instead of having what you suggested I had a second class for it... Beginners mistakes.